# Why do MutableSharedFlows and flowOf work differently when they are combined?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

```
@Test
fun sharedFlowCombine() = runBlocking {
    val a = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()
    val b = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()
    var resultCount = 0

    launch {
        combine(a, b) { mA, mB ->
            mA + mB
        }.collect {
            resultCount += 1
        }
    }

    launch {
        a.emit(1)
        b.emit(1)
        b.emit(2)
        b.emit(3)
    }

    delay(1000)
    assertThat(resultCount).isEqualTo(3)
}
```

I wrote test code that combines two `MutableSharedFlow` and I expected they combine values as below.

(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)

However, the result says the `resultCount` is 0. I also wrote that runs with common flow.

```
@Test
fun flowCombine(): Unit = runBlocking {
    val a = flowOf(1, 2, 3)
    val b = flowOf(1)
    var resultCount = 0

    launch {
        combine(a, b) { mA, mB ->
            mA + mB
        }.collect {
            resultCount += 1
        }
    }

    delay(1000)
    assertThat(resultCount).isEqualTo(3)
}
```

It just works. The test passed the assertion. What is difference between `flowOf` and `MutableSharedFlow` that makes test different?

*Edited*

I guessed that emitting value to MutableSharedFlow sequentially makes it suspend. So I also changed my test code as below. It does not work too. Actual `resultCount` was 0.

```
@Test
fun sharedFlowCombine() = runBlocking {
    val a = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()
    val b = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()
    var resultCount = 0

    launch {
        combine(a, b) { mA, mB ->
            mA + mB
        }.collect {
            resultCount += 1
        }
    }

    launch {
        a.emit(1)
    }
    launch {
        b.emit(1)
    }
    launch {
        b.emit(2)
    }
    launch {
        b.emit(3)
    }

    delay(1000)
    assertThat(resultCount).isEqualTo(3)
}
```

Comment: I think it’s because you’re using `runBlocking`’s default single-threaded dispatcher to launch your inner coroutines, so the second coroutine that emits values never gets a chance to start because the first coroutine that collects never returns. If you use a specific dispatcher for at least one of the two launch calls, it should work. Or swap the order of the two launched coroutines.

Comment: I found adding `replay=1` in each constructors and `delay(100)` between each emit solves the problem. But I want to know why.

Comment: `delay(100)` (or `yield()`) relinquishes the thread back to the dispatcher and allows the first coroutine to take another step before it suspends again. So maybe it prevents the flow in the first coroutine from missing the first emitted item from A. IMO, it is not worth analyzing such a complicated scenario that you would never use in production code. You will never be emitting and collecting with a flow from the same single-threaded dispatcher.